# How to use gradle to set testOnly attribute in manifest

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Gradle gives the ability to set some manifest attributes pretty simply like:

`targetSdkVersion` and `minSdkVersion`

Is there any way to add the android:testOnly application attribute with gradle without touching the manifest by hand

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#testOnly

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom resource value with Gradle. E.g. in your app module's *build.gradle* under *android* -> *defaultConfig*

```
resValue("bool", "test_only", "true")
```

And then in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:testOnly="@bool/test_only"
```

E.g. you can set this to different values for different flavors

Comment: But how can I do it without touching the manifest? I've edited the question

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot add this directly in the Android manifest? You could modify the merged manifest itself, but it's more troublesome and hacky. See https://gist.github.com/MarkMjw/7998381

Comment: Yes, there is a reason I can't directly add it to the manifest, that is why the question is stated as such.